# How to trigger aframe's orientation modal?

Tags: aframe

I am working on an aframe project, and I would like to trigger the orientation modal when the screen is vertical for iOS.

Is this a default aframe behavior?

If this is a default aframe behavior, then I must have disabled it. How do I re-enable this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the orientation modal is on by default, and it was turned off in my project.

```
// Issue
this.element.nativeElement.setAttribute('vr-mode-ui', 'enabled', 'false');

// Fix
this.element.nativeElement.setAttribute('vr-mode-ui', 'enabled', 'true');
```